# Hi, i'm learning python and i can't seem to ignore an if statement

Tags: python

I am trying to make a little guessing game, here's the code

```
secret_w = "giraffe"
guess= ""
guess_remain = 3
guess_c = 0
guess_limit = 2
outofguesses = False


while guess != secret_w and not(outofguesses):
    guess = input("I'm thinking of an animal, try and guess it!  ")
    guess_c += 1
    if guess != secret_w:
        print("Incorrect, try again")
        guess_remain -= 1
        print("You've guessed", guess_c, "times and have", guess_remain, "guesses left!")

    if guess_c == 1:
        print("Hint 1: It's tall!")
    if guess_c == 2:
        print("Hint 2: It has spots and a long neck")


    if guess_c > guess_limit:
        outofguesses = True




if outofguesses:
    print("You're out of guesses, better luck next time!")


if guess == secret_w:
    print("Well done")
    print("You got it on attempt number", guess_c )
```

If I run it, it works fine, if I guess it wrong 3 times, it ends which is perfect, but if I guess it right the first time, it still says "hint 1: it's tall" which clearly I don't want to happen, and same goes if i guess it correctly on guess 2, it gives me hint 2.

I've tried making true and false statements but nothing seems to work?

Ignore my spaghetti code, I know I have to practice making it shorter and so on.

Comment: Why not simplify this by removing `outofguesses` and just pushing that `guess_c > guess_limit` logic into the `while` loop, as in `while guess != secret_w and guess_c <= guess_limit`.

Comment: You're checking that *both* the guess is incorrect *and* they're not out of guesses. A correct guess, but still having more guesses means it continues.

Comment: You should replace `if guess_c == 1`  with `if guess_remain == 2`

Comment: @tadman okay, so i tried, that and it still gave me the hint even when guessed correctly (idk how to reply to certain comments tbh.

Comment: Are you familiar with `else`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am kind of.. How would an else help me out here?

Comment: Not answering the question, but you have an antipattern there: two independent parameters (guess limit and the current attempt) expressed as three variables. What happens when you almost inevitably forget to update one of them at some point of writing the code? You have a bug. Do not have more entities than you need, instead, use functions for derived qualities (for expensive calculations, results may be cached). If you need to make the code more readable, use local variables - this will reduce the possibility of introducing unwanted side effects if different parts of code change them.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.lower()` method on the input to make sure it is in lowercase so it matches your secret word by using it this way:

```
guess = input("I'm thinking of an animal, try and guess it! : ").lower()
```

Notice the `.lower()` in the end, it automatically makes the user input all  lowercase.

Secondly you need to have the `if` statements nested correctly like so:

```
    if guess != secret_w:
        print("Incorrect, try again")
        guess_remain -= 1
        print("You've guessed", guess_c, "times and have", guess_remain, "guesses left!")
    if guess_c == 1 and guess != secret_w:
        print("Hint 1: It's tall!")
    if guess_c == 2 and guess != secret_w:
        print("Hint 2: It has spots and a long neck")
    if guess_c > guess_limit:
        outofguesses = True
```

Also we check if it is not the secret word on every try. This works for your solution.

So for clarity, the whole working code would look like this:

```
secret_w = "giraffe"
guess= ""
guess_remain = 3
guess_c = 0
guess_limit = 2
outofguesses = False

while guess != secret_w and not(outofguesses):
    guess = input("I'm thinking of an animal, try and guess it! : ").lower()
    guess_c += 1
    if guess != secret_w:
        print("Incorrect, try again")
        guess_remain -= 1
        print("You've guessed", guess_c, "times and have", guess_remain, "guesses left!")
    if guess_c == 1 and guess != secret_w:
        print("Hint 1: It's tall!")
    if guess_c == 2 and guess != secret_w:
        print("Hint 2: It has spots and a long neck")
    if guess_c > guess_limit:
        outofguesses = True

if outofguesses:
    print("You're out of guesses, better luck next time!")

if guess == secret_w:
    print("Well done")
    print("You got it on attempt number", guess_c )
```

Comment: Ahhhhh that makes a lot more sense, i've seen alot of code using .lower() and i wasn't too sure why, I thought it meant that the answer you give HAD to be in lower for it to be correct if used in your code, thanks for clearing this up

Answer (score 0):

Because you increase guess_c by 1 every time the user enters a guess means that even if they get it right it is still being called because guess_c is still being increased.

If you want to stop this you can check if it is correct before you run the conditions for the checks. Also if you want the program to stop after you get it right, add a break to stop the loop.

```
secret_w = "giraffe"
guess= ""
guess_remain = 3
guess_c = 0
guess_limit = 2
outofguesses = False


while guess != secret_w and not(outofguesses):
    guess = input("I'm thinking of an animal, try and guess it!  ")
    guess_c += 1
    if outofguesses:
      print("You're out of guesses, better luck next time!")
  
    if guess == secret_w:
      print("Well done")
      print("You got it on attempt number", guess_c )
      break
    if guess != secret_w:
        print("Incorrect, try again")
        guess_remain -= 1
        print("You've guessed", guess_c, "times and have", guess_remain, "guesses left!")

    if guess_c == 1:
        print("Hint 1: It's tall!")
    if guess_c == 2:
        print("Hint 2: It has spots and a long neck")


    if guess_c > guess_limit:
        outofguesses = True
```

And instead of adding a variable you can just break the loop using `break` which will end a loop.

```
while True:
  break
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes a lot more sense, i didn't know break was a thing, i thought it had to run through the loop or if the word was guessed to end it, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I learned it myself not too long ago. Also another loop tip, if you want to check one condition and if that is true to not check any others, use `continue` and it will restart the loop without going through the rest of the code @matthewwaring

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but can you use that in an example on my code? I'm not quite following on how it would be used.

Comment: So if I put in 0, it wouldn't check if the number is 1.
                                                                                 

while True:
  user = input("Input A number 1 - 3")

  if int(user) <= 0:
    print("Not a valid number")
    continue
  if int(user) == 1:
    print("VALID NUMBER")
    continue
  if int(user) == 2:
    print("VALID NUMBER")
    continue

  if int(user) == 3:
    print("VALID NUMBER")
    continue

Answer (score 0):

It must be on nested If condition so that it will not show when you guess right answer. Always compare strings as `case-insensitive` and break a `while loop` when condition satisfied. Here is your modified code

```
secret_w = "giraffe"
guess= ""
guess_remain = 3
guess_c = 0
guess_limit = 2
outofguesses = False


while guess != secret_w and not(outofguesses):
    guess = input("I'm thinking of an animal, try and guess it!  ")
    guess_c += 1
    
    if guess.lower() != secret_w.lower():
        print("Incorrect, try again")
        guess_remain -= 1
        print("You've guessed", guess_c, "times and have", guess_remain, "guesses left!")

        if guess_c == 1:
            print("Hint 1: It's tall!")
        if guess_c == 2:
            print("Hint 2: It has spots and a long neck")
        if outofguesses:
            print("You're out of guesses, better luck next time!")
    else:
        print("Well done")
        print("You got it on attempt number", guess_c )
        break


    if guess_c > guess_limit:
        outofguesses = True
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes a lot more sense, i didn't know break was a thing, i thought it had to run through the loop or if the word was guessed to end it, Thanks a lot!